# C to Assembly MIPS by Cross Compiler (need explain $sp, $fp)

Tags: c, assembly, mips

After compiling this C code :

```
int main(void)
{
   unsigned int i = 5;
   switch(i)
   {
      case 1: i = i + 3; break;
      case 5: i = i<<3; break;
      case 10: i = i>>2;
   }
}
```

i have this Assembly MIPS :

```
.file   1 "SwitchCase.c"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .ent    main
main:
    .frame  $fp,16,$31      # vars= 8, regs= 1/0, args= 0, gp= 0
    .mask   0x40000000,-8
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-16
    sw  $fp,8($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    li  $2,5            # 0x5
    sw  $2,0($fp)
    lw  $2,0($fp)
    sw  $2,4($fp)
    li  $2,5            # 0x5
    lw  $3,4($fp)
    beq $3,$2,$L4
    lw  $3,4($fp)
    sltu    $2,$3,6
    beq $2,$0,$L6
    li  $2,1            # 0x1
    lw  $3,4($fp)
    beq $3,$2,$L3
    j   $L2
$L6:
    li  $2,10           # 0xa
    lw  $3,4($fp)
    beq $3,$2,$L5
    j   $L2
$L3:
    lw  $2,0($fp)
    addiu   $2,$2,3
    sw  $2,0($fp)
    j   $L2
$L4:
    lw  $2,0($fp)
    sll $2,$2,3
    sw  $2,0($fp)
    j   $L2
$L5:
    lw  $2,0($fp)
    srl $2,$2,2
    sw  $2,0($fp)
$L2:
    move    $sp,$fp
    lw  $fp,8($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,16
    j   $31
    .end    main
```

I don't really understand this Assembly MIPS, especially the instructions with **$sp, $fp** register (the purpose of those registers for this code), could someone help me explain this asm?

Comment: You have to be more specific. What is it that you don't understand about it?

Comment: i think that just by having subprogram that we have to use $sp, $fp, but i don't use any subprogram(procedure) here, why this code have $sp, $fp registers ?

Comment: @VAK: keep in mind that this assembly code has a lot of "unnecessary" code since it's built with no optimizations.  If it had been optimized, the `main()` function would likely have been essentially empty.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: so could you help me or give me some clues to optimize this code, i have least experience on assembly languague :(

Comment: i think i can optimize a little bit the algorithm for this code to have it shorter but not much

Comment: The code doesn't need programmer optimization - it's just do-nothing, example toy code presumably so you can study the output. If you're using GCC, add the `-O2` option and you'll probably see most of `main()` disappear from the assembly listing because the compiler will see that nothing externally visible is ever actually done with `i`.

Comment: @Dolda2000 this code line `j $31` doesn't mean anything here, right ? because $ra doesn't hold any address, so can i just remove this line ?

Comment: @VAK: the `j $31` is the return from `main()`.

Comment: @VAK: What makes you think `$ra` doesn't hold an address? The return address would have been put into it by the `jal` instruction in the function that called your `main`. You are aware that `$ra` is simply an alias for `$31`, right? If you remove that line, the CPU will just continue running whatever bogus instructions that follow after your `main` after it's done, which is most likely not what you'd want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging the actual question from the comments:*'"i think that just by having subprogram that we have to use $sp, $fp, but i don't use any subprogram(procedure) here, why this code have $sp, $fp registers ?"*

For one thing, `main` still needs a stackframe of its own to hold local variables (and temporary, non-named values), so that's why it needs a valid frame-pointer (`$fp`).

If you're wondering why it saves the previous frame-pointer, that's because even `main` is called by other functions (usually called `_start` in some CRT library), which needs to have its frame preserved.

Whether main calls other subroutines in turn is irrelevant, because that doesn't free it from its own need for a stackframe, as above.

Also, it is usually specified as part of a platform's ABI that all functions should set up proper frames, regardlessly of whether they actually need them. This is because a proper frame-chain on the stack is often useful for debuggers and other analysis tools, and it often turns out afterwards to be a pain to lack them in time of need (such as post-mortem debugging of a crashed program). If you really want to, however, you can tell most compilers to omit them in violation of the ABI by use of some compiler-specific flag like `-fomit-frame-pointer`.

Answer (score 2):

The information can be found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture). `$sp` stands for **stack pointer**, `$fp` for **frame pointer**.

Your `main()` creates a frame for its variables on the stack. The frame is 16 bytes long.

```
addiu   $sp,$sp,-16   # reserve 16 B on stack
sw  $fp,8($sp)        # store previous frame pointer onto stack
move    $fp,$sp       # set frame pointer for main()
# ...
lw  $2,0($fp)         # load a value from $fp+0 to register 2
sw  $2,4($fp)         # save a value to $fp+4 from register 2
# ...
move    $sp,$fp       # reverting the first 3 instructions now
lw  $fp,8($sp)
addiu   $sp,$sp,16
```

@Dolda2000 has explained *why* this is done.

Comment: But what is the meaning, usefulness of these instructions with $sp, $fp in this asm ?